# How do I give lists a specific height so they move into a new column next to it?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to give a list (< ul >) a specific height or similar, where it just moves the items (< li >) into a new column if there are too many?

I've illustrated it here:

http://oi47.tinypic.com/2dqj5gg.jpg

The red box has a specific height. When there are more items than there's space available it should simple just move them up to the next row as it does with "List7, List8, List9" in my example

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS column-count some way like this:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}​
```

Though it's not universally supported and challenged browsers will just ignore it. For them you'd have to do something non-semantic like manually splitting it into more than one UL and floating them or something equally horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using `column-count`:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Although this is not supported in all browsers. You can use a javascript plugin to polyfill, or just use progressive enhancement (it’s a list after all).

http://jsfiddle.net/ASDkz/

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to `float` your `li` tags, like this:

```
ul
{
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

li
{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    width: 50px;
}
```

But this will give you the following structure:

```
List1    List2    List3
List4    List5
```

If you specifically need the structure in your provided image then you may need to look at some dynamic rendering with jQuery to get full browser support.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ze6R8/)

Comment: That's more like the kind of list people put in horizontally-arranged footers than the OP picture - I think he's after a more magazine column look.

Comment: @moopet yeah that's what I thought too, but as we can see from the other answers a pure CSS way of doing this can be difficult and incompatible. I'd personally do this dynamically in script using a modulus calculation to sort into cols.